# OSX popup to find FinderSyncAPIExtension

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

After my recent upgrade in OSX, it is showing with message:
"Where is FinderSyncAPIExtension?"

https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0Bz_3NOSxzC7NWlpmVXNrRW5yWVk

Any idea, what is this?

Comment: I think this might go better on the [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) SEs since it is related to computer program use and not related to creating computer programs.

Comment: I have asked the same question on Ask Different: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227216/where-is-findersyncapiextension-google-drive

Answer (score 11):

See same question on https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6890881

OS X asks Where is FinderSyncAPIExtension on startup

It seems to be GDrive, restart it and you should be OK